# Use the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition of continuity to prove $f$ is continuous on $[-\infty,1)\cup (1,5]$ and that it is not continuous at $1$

Tags: continuity, piecewise-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{\leq 5}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      x & x\leq 1 \\ 4-2x & 1< x\leq 5  \end{cases}$

Use the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition of continuity to prove $f$ is continuous on $[-\infty,1)\cup (1,5]$ and that it is not continuous at $1$

---

I am not sure how to go about this problem, should I prove each interval is continuous separately and then prove it is discontinuous at 1? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes.  Prove it for each interval.  (Note: In selecting your $\delta$ make sure $\delta < 1-x$ for $x\le 1$ and $\delta < \min (x-1, 5-x)$ if $1 < x \le 5$).  Then to prove $x$ is not continuous at $x=1$.  Compare what $f(1-\epsilon)$ is to $f(1 + \epsilon)$ is.

Answer (score 0):

For  $x\le1 $, let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.   Choose  $\delta=\epsilon  $.  Then  $\vert x-y\vert \lt \delta \implies \vert f (y)-f (x)\vert =\vert y-x \vert \lt \delta = \epsilon  $.   Thus  $f$ is continuous for $x\lt 1$.

Similarly for $1\lt x \le 5$ if $\epsilon \gt 0$ is given, let $\delta \lt \frac\epsilon2 $.  Then $\vert y-x \vert \lt \delta \implies  \vert f (y)-f (x) \vert =\vert (4-2y)-(4-2x)\vert=\vert 2 (x-y )\vert\lt 2\cdot\frac \epsilon 2=\epsilon  $.  Thus f is continuous.

Finally,  for  $x=1$, given  $\epsilon \lt 1$, there are $y $ with  $\vert y-x \vert\lt \delta $, for any  $\delta\gt 0 $, such that  $\vert f (y)-f (1)\vert \gt \epsilon  $.  Namely,  let $y=1+\eta$, where  $0\lt \eta\lt \delta $.  Then $\vert f(y) -f (1)\vert=\vert (4-2y)-1\vert=3-2(1+\eta)\vert=\vert 1-2\eta\vert\ge  1-\vert 2\eta\vert \gt \epsilon $ for sufficiently small $\eta $...  In particular,

> $\eta \lt min (\delta,1-\frac\epsilon2) $ will do. ..